# Link to my Facebook profile and to my website on share buttons

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, share, customization

I have a website with links to news. Each story has a Facebook share button and a tweet button. When an user retweets the new, the tweet has a reference to my twitter profile. Is there a way to do the same for the share button on facebook? This is: when an user shares through Facebook a link of any of the news shown in my website, the message displayed on his wall, will be accompanied by a link to my facebook profile and to my website.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sharing the link to the news directly, why not share the link of the page on your website which contains the link to the news? The purpose of the "Share" button on your website is to get you more social traffic, not the news sites!